# Accessing Post ID Within Loop

Tags: posts, loop, terms, id

I have a page called Products with an ID of '8'

Within that, I have the following template part
`<?php get_template_part('loop', 'feed-products' ); ?>`

Then within *that* file, I have this template part:
`<?php get_template_part('loop', 'brand-product' ); ?>`

Then within the Brand Product file, I am trying to get a list of terms based on the ID of the post in each loop interation:
`$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'brand-product' );`

But instead, it is giving me the ID of the Products page (so '8') and outputting this error

> Undefined variable: brand

I've tried `global $post;` but that didn't work

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is the code for loop-brand-product.php (the error points to each `case` statement within the `switch`

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'brand-product' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { 

$brand = array();

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $brand[] = $term->term_id;
    echo $term;
}

$brand = join( ", ", $brand );

}

switch ($brand) {
    case 3:
        $img = 'logo-amazon-brand.png';
        break;

    case 5:
        $img = 'logo-dc-brand.gif';
        break;

    case 8:
        $img = 'logo-huebsch-brand.png';
        break;

    case 4:
        $img = 'logo-miele-brand.gif';
        break;

    case 9:
        $img = 'logo-speed-queen-brand.gif';
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you turned on debugging? It doesn't seem obvious anywhere where just "brand" is a possible variable. I would suggest turning on [Debug Log](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) and post the exactly line you get this error.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks, do you mean in wp-config.php? I have that enabled. Also, I've edited the end of my original question to include the code that the errors refer to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably comes from whenever a `$post` has no terms set. You need to set `$brand = array()` outside your `IF` statement, add it just under `get_the_terms()`. At that point it also wouldn't hurt to wrap your `switch` statement in a `if( ! empty( $brand ) ) {`

Another problem I see with this code is that you're adding your term IDs to an array, then converting that array to a string, then switching them on an integer. So if you have a post assigned to `Term 3` and `Term 5`, whenever it hits your join it will convert to string: `'3, 5'` and test the entire string against each case:

`'3, 5' == 3` -> `False`

`'3, 5' == 5` -> `False`

etc. You may just want to get the First term and test on that.

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks! Also will look at the array / string issue you mentioned. Is the best way to do it just to add a `break` statement so that the loop only runs once and assign the value to a variable instead of an array?

Comment: By the looks of your system you only need 1 term, so if you *know* that there are `$terms`, which is already in array, you could just say `$brand = $terms[0]->term_id` then run through your switch statement. That would negate the need for the `foreach` and the `join()`